# jQuery - Only first element of the array is taken

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

i have searched of this issue on the internet but i dont find anything similar.

i have an array in php. i passed this array to javascript function to check and disable checkboxes if their values are the same to the ones in the array. however, the function seems to only take the first element of the array to disable only one checkbox.

for example i have 3 elements A11,A10,A9 in my php array. when i passed this array to the js function, it made only the checkbox A11 checked and disabled. Why is that?

below is the code for the array i have in php:

```
$query = "SELECT reserved FROM et_seats WHERE event_id = '$theatre->id'";
$reserved = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reserved)){
    array_push($array, $row[0]);
}
```

and below is the function in javascript that i have:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      var reserved = <?php echo '["' . implode('","', $array) . '"]' ?>;
      var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seats');
      for (var i = 0; i <= seats.length; i++) {
        reserved.map(function(v) {
          if (seats[i].value === v) {
            seats[i].setAttribute("disabled", "true");
            seats[i].setAttribute("checked", "true");
          }
        });
      }
    });

</script>
```

why does the function only take the first element in the array? where did i do wrong? i suspect it's the line where i change the php array to javascript. i have also tried `var reserved = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;` but it still doesn't work

here is a snippet of my html checkboxes. they are actually for a seat plan

```
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A3">
</td>
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A2">
</td>
<td>
 <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A1">
</td>
```

Comment: @Nick yes, i've tried that one too, same result.

Comment: Can you share a bit of your HTML?

Comment: sure, i have included in my question

Comment: Other than the `<= seats.length` which should be `< seats.length` your code works fine as long as `reserved` has a valid value. Have you checked the value of `reserved` in a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The actual problem was that the values in the table had leading spaces on them. Changing

```
array_push($array, $row[0]);
```

to

```
array_push($array, trim($row[0]));
```

solved the problem.

**Original Answer**

Other than the `<= seats.length` which should be `< seats.length`, your code works fine as long as `reserved` is getting a valid array value. I would however use `indexOf` rather than `map` on `reserved` to find if the `seats[i].value` is in the array.

```js
$(function() {
  var reserved = ["A1","A6","A4"];
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seats');
  for (i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    var seat = seats[i];
    if (reserved.indexOf(seat.value) >= 0) {
        seat.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        seat.setAttribute("checked", "true");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A6">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A5">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A4">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A3">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A2">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A1">
</td>
```

Note that since you are using jQuery you may as well use the [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) function to simplify the code:

```js
$(function() {
  var reserved = ["A1","A6","A4"];
  $('.seats').each(function () {
    if (reserved.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
        $(this).attr("checked", "true");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A6">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A5">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A4">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A3">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A2">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A1">
</td>
```

Comment: yes it works when the array values are manually set like that. but when i try to get the array value from php array, it reads only the first element. that is my issue now

Comment: @the.mungk Have you looked at the value of `reserved` in the debugger? is it e.g. `["A2,A3"]` or `["A2","A3"]`? i.e. is each value of `reserved` in the `et_seats` an individual seat or a comma separated list?

Comment: how do i do that? sorry i'm such a noob at this

Comment: @the.mungk you could try adding `alert(reserved.join('-'))`. Or can you just check the values in the table?

Comment: i got B15- B14- B13 and that's equivalent to ["B15", "B14", "B13"] right?

Comment: Looks like you might have spaces in the values - what happens if you change `array_push($array, $row[0]);` to `array_push($array, trim($row[0]));`?

Comment: OMG YES THEY'RE ALL  NOW CHECKED AND DISABLED. THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUU

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery use forEach. like below. hope this helps. what I can see is `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection and for some browsers index won't work like `seats[i]` this for HTMLCollections.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      var reserved = <?php echo '["' . implode('","', $array) . '"]' ?>;
      var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seats');
      [].forEach.call(seats, function(el) {
        reserved.map(function(v) {
          if (el.value === v) {
            el.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
            el.setAttribute("checked", "true");
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: still same result :(

Comment: did you try ```json_encode``` instead of implode ? like ```var reserved = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;```

Comment: yes. and it still takes only the first element in the array

Comment: what's the browser you are testing this? is it IE? and the PHP version ?

Comment: it's okay i got it figured out already. i'm using the latest PHP7 i think and chrome. thanks!

Comment: ah ok no problem :)